# How should I say more polite in such situation?

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, sentence-usage, sentence-choice

Recently, my downstairs neighbor always slam the door, and that is so annoying. Which of the following utterances should I use?

1. > The noise from you slamming the door is so loud. Could you be more quiet?
2. > Could you quit slamming the door? It's so annoying.
3. > Could you just stop slamming the door? Frankly, that is making so much noise as I study in my room.

By the way, are my examples grammatically correct?

Answer (score 3):

Your examples are just fine, (non-related: when writting, use an "space" after a comma), you could add "please" to them.

Personally, I would go with "Could you please be more careful when closing the door? I'm studing for my finals and I have to be really focused.

Comment: Essential here is not using the word *slamming*: This avoids the accusation that your neighbor **is** slamming the door. He (she) may not perceive that as such (or may not even be aware of it) and start to defend himslf.